# MS C++ disable function reordering

Tags: c

How to disable compiler/linker optimization that reorders functions in a program?
Let's say, I have three functions, like

```
    void A (){};
    void B (){};
    void C (){};
```

After build, these functions could be re-ordered, so that B comes first in memory, C - second and A - third.

In GCC, you have an option "no-toplevel-reorder" that does the trick.

> -fno-toplevel-reorder
>
> Do not reorder top-level functions, variables, and asm statements.
>   Output them in the same order that they appear in the input file. When
>   this option is used, unreferenced static variables are not removed.
>   This option is intended to support existing code that relies on a
>   particular ordering. For new code, it is better to use attributes.

Is there an analogue for MS C++?

Comment: why would you want to do such a thing?

Comment: No, there is no such option. How would that be useful?

Comment: I'm converting some old asm code, that needs it. Kind of firmware stuff. If there's no such an option, I have to consider using gcc... Thank you for the answer!

Answer (score 1):

It could be done using #pragma code_seg("segname$tag");